# PHP And jQuery - Chat Security

Tags: php, ajax, chat

I have a problem I can't solve.

I have built a chat for an online game, and I want that every page will have a different chat room.
The url goes like this = `play.php?plc=[arena/advanture/bank/...]`.

I have a SQL table named `pages` that defines every page. For instance:

```
╔════╦══════════════╗
║ id ║  name        ║
╠════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║ arena        ║
║  2 ║ advanture    ║
║  3 ║ bank         ║
║  4 ║ weapons      ║
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

Every page do his uniqe calculations, if you're allowed to go in, or you can't.
if you can't, I do `header()`, and `exit;`.

I'll explain how it's connected to the problem.

How can the ajax file know whether the page was successfuly served, or the permission denied and the `exit`ed?

I thought about putting a hidden `<input>`, but then it'll be hackble. If a user can't go into the page, he can still change the input value to some id, and get access to the page's chat.

Comment: use a session perhaps...?

Comment: i think you should use a session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax-file can get the param via `window.location` but you should use a session in php, otherwise users can manipulate this value and read all chats even if they're not there.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['area'] = ...;
```

Comment: session won't prevent the user from changing the querystring (hence, the session var) in the address bar, unless the querystring contains an ID that the server-side script can resolve

Comment: Yes, of corse `$_SESSION['area']` should not be set without checking if user is allowed to enter this area.

Comment: Yes, because session can be changed too. So I'll check it in play.php. Am I right ?

Comment: @ArielAharonson The server controls your session and you can't change it directly. Indirectly, you can change whatever inputs that is sent to the server. Assuming that your php script is strongly validating that the user should be allowed or not, it is quite secure.